# WP8: ListBox last row won't remain scrolled into view

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox

When vertically scrolling into view, I can pull the last row into view, but on releasing the drag, the last row springs back (partially) out of view. I think inaccuracy of measure can be attributed to a grid that I'm using as the listbox's header but I'm currently unable to fix this to that they work together correctly.

```
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid x:Name="_headers"/>
                    <ListBox x:Name="_dataGrid"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

**Update
This example removes the scroll and also suffers from the same truncated row problem as the example above. The header grid row also doesn't scroll horizontally with the listbox rows which is an even bigger problem for my solution.

```
    <Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Grid x:Name="_headers"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="_dataGrid"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put `ScrollViewer` inside `StackPanel`. `StackPanel` doesn't limit control's size so the `ScrollViewer` can grow forever and never scroll properly. Its size must be limited. `Grid` can do it perfectly (if only the height of the row is set to `*`, not `Auto`).

Also, in my opinion you shouldn't put `ListBox` inside `ScrollViewer`, because `ListBox` already has its own scroll feature.

Answer (score 0):

Never ever use a `ListBox` inside a `ScrollViewer`, you will run into scrolling conflicts.

As far as I can see, you need to add a header to your list. `LongListSeelctor` might be the best option, since it has got a `Header` property (also `Footer`):

See: http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth